Add edge to a graph with std::reference_wrapper bundled property
I have a boost::adjacency_list with a bundled property for the nodes.
    using KinematicGraph =
        boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS,
                              boost::vecS,
                              boost::bidirectionalS,
                              Model::SimulationObjects::map<std::reference_wrapper>::as<std::variant>>;

I am trying to add an edge to a graph using boost::add_edge function
                                auto from = reinterpret_cast<const void *>(std::addressof(mapping.from()));
                                auto to = reinterpret_cast<const void *>(std::addressof(mapping.to()));

                                boost::add_edge(vertexMap[from], vertexMap[to], m_simulationObjectsGraph);

where vertexMap is just     std::unordered_map<const void *, KinematicGraph::vertex_descriptor> vertexMap;, which I use to keep track of the added vertices.
However, this code doesn't compile.
[build] In file included from /home/dev/.conan2/p/b/boosta593711c2d7a0/p/include/boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp:255:
[build] /home/dev/.conan2/p/b/boosta593711c2d7a0/p/include/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp:2453:17: error: call to implicitly-deleted default constructor of 'std::variant<std::reference_wrapper<mandos::SimulationObject<mandos::Particle3DTag>>>'
[build]  2453 |                 bidir_rand_stored_vertex() {}

I have no clue why it says its not able to instantiate the bundled property of a vertex, I haven't ask for it.
If I remove the add_edge line, compiles fine.
Here is a minimal example showing the error
https://godbolt.org/z/94bnsj9MP

For your minimal example, when I change the VertexProperties to std::variant<std::monostate, std::reference_wrapper<S>> it works.

I guess that makes sense, as it converts the variant into default constructible. Probably I'll remove the ref and use a pointer, I know that the lifetime will be valid

@jjcasmar that's probably the way to go, as the documentation states that properties need to be default constructible

Can you point to that part of the documentation? I couldn't find it

@jjcasmar The types of all property values must be Copy Constructible, Assignable, and Default Constructible
